# Is there an R dplyr equivalent for unix "more"?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a scenario of couple hundred thousand rows in my df arranged in 8 groups and I want to be able to tab through the top 100 or so. I would like to do the same what you do with Unix's `more`. Here is a similar reproducible example using the `stop_words` data frame from `tidytext` package. I would like to find out the 100 words at the end of the alphabet in each of the three groups. I tried:

```
> stop_words %>% group_by(lexicon) %>% arrange(desc(word)) %>% print(n=20)
# A tibble: 1,149 x 2
# Groups:   lexicon [3]
   word       lexicon 
   <chr>      <chr>   
 1 zero       SMART   
 2 z          SMART   
 3 yourselves SMART   
 4 yourselves snowball
 5 yourself   SMART   
 6 yourself   snowball
 7 yours      SMART   
 8 yours      snowball
 9 yours      onix    
10 your       SMART   
11 your       snowball
12 your       onix    
13 youngest   onix    
14 younger    onix    
15 young      onix    
16 you've     SMART   
17 you've     snowball
18 you're     SMART   
19 you're     snowball
20 you'll     SMART   
# ... with 1,129 more rows
```

but it does not let me hit spacebar to tab through the results, and it does not even give me the top 20 from each group. If I replace the last command in the pipe with `top_n(20)` it still does not give me groups of 20, but there I think it is because there are no numeric columns to rank based on.

Does anyone know how to add an equivalent of `more` to the end of my pipe? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would think this might be entirely dependent on whatever interface you're actually using to interact with R

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `slice_tail` function.

```
stop_words %>% group_by(lexicon) %>% slice_tail(n = 20)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for more of a `more` functionality instead of getting at the tail of the df. like if there are 100 options at the end of the `group_by`, to be able to hit the spacebar and scan through them. thank you though.